# Print search field in template file

Tags: theming, 8, search

I need a search field to "pop down" under a search icon *({# Search icon #} in sample code)* in my template file.

But how do i print the search block directly into a template file?

I want it to be in my menu--main--site-main-menu.html.twig

```
    {% import _self as menus %}

          {#
            We call a macro which calls itself to render the full tree.
            @see http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html
          #}
          {{ menus.menu_links(items, attributes, 0) }}

          {% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
          {% import _self as menus %}

          {% if items %}

          {# List #}
          {% if menu_level == 0 %}
<ul{{ attributes.addClass('layout-navigation layout-navigation layout-navigation--full-width layout--large-screen-only') }}>
    {% else %}
    <ul{{ attributes.addClass('layout-navigation__dropdown-menu') }}>
        {% endif %}

        {% for item in items %}
            {% set item_classes = [
            item.in_active_trail ? 'active',
            ] %}

            {# List item #}
            {% if item.below and item.is_expanded %}
            <li{{ item.attributes.addClass('layout-navigation__dropdown', item_classes) }}>
            {% else %}
                <li{{ item.attributes.addClass('layout-navigation__link', item_classes) }}>
            {% endif %}

            {# Link #}
            {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}

            {# Submenu #}
            {% if item.below %}
                {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes.removeClass('layout-navigation layout--large-screen-only'), menu_level + 1) }}
            {% endif %}

            </li>
        {% endfor %}

        {# Search icon #}
        <li class="layout-navigation__link layout-navigation__link__icon"><a href="search/node"><span class="icon fa fa-search"></span></a></li>

    </ul>
    {% endif %}

    {% endmacro %}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to preprocess the menu and inject it as a variable, then print the variable:

```
use Drupal\block\Entity\Block;

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_menu().
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_menu(&$variables) {
  $block = Block::load('myblock');
  $variables['myblock'] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('block')->view($block);
}
```

Then in your template:

```
{{ myblock }}
```